# Changing canvas for drawing lines

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this in a stackoverflow question on how to draw in canvas http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/kneDX/ but I want it to draw lines continuously without the circles but smooth lines. The code to be changed is below:

```
ctx.fillCircle = function(x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.fill();
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to find all the points between the mouse start and end, and then fill the points between using `fillRect`. The reason you need to use the line algorithm is because if a user moves the mouse too fast you wont get solid lines, but lines with gaps. I modified your function quite a bit to do this. You can also pass a line thickness value to change how large you want the stroke to be. Note the same could be applied using `arcs` I just prefer `rect`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/kneDX/879/)**

```
   (function() {
    // Creates a new canvas element and appends it as a child
    // to the parent element, and returns the reference to
    // the newly created canvas element

    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        canvas.lastX = 0;
        canvas.lastY = 0;
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
        var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height);
        var ctx = canvas.context;

        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function(x1, y1, x2, y2, fillColor, lineThickness) {
            this.fillStyle = fillColor;

            var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
            if (steep) {
                var x = x1;
                x1 = y1;
                y1 = x;

                var y = y2;
                y2 = x2;
                x2 = y;
            }
            if (x1 > x2) {
                var x = x1;
                x1 = x2;
                x2 = x;

                var y = y1;
                y1 = y2;
                y2 = y;
            }

            var dx = x2 - x1,
                dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
                error = 0,
                de = dy / dx,
                yStep = -1,
                y = y1;

            if (y1 < y2) {
                yStep = 1;
            }

            for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
                if (steep) {
                    this.fillRect(y, x, lineThickness, lineThickness);
                } else {
                    this.fillRect(x, y, lineThickness, lineThickness);
                }

                error += de;
                if (error >= 0.5) {
                    y += yStep;
                    error -= 1.0;
                }
            }

        };
        ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
            ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        };
        ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.node.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
                return;
            }
            mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            ctx.fillCircle(mouseX,mouseY,canvas.lastX,canvas.lastY,"#000",1);

            canvas.lastX = mouseX;
            canvas.lastY = mouseY;

        };
        canvas.node.onmousedown = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = true;
            canvas.lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
            canvas.lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
        };
        canvas.node.onmouseup = function(e) {
            canvas.isDrawing = false;
        };
    }

    var container = document.getElementById('canvas');
    init(container, 200, 200, '#ddd');

})();​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

If i understand,you need this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-lines/

This script draw a line from 0,0 to mouse.

window.event.clientX = mouse x coordinate
window.event.clientY = mouse y coordinate

```
<script>
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(0,0);
  context.lineTo(window.event.clientX,window.event.clientY);
  context.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: yes but how to do this dynamically when you move the mouse and not static?